# How to control the height of Blazor Virtualize component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a basic Blazor Virtualize component. As a test I just add a List with "1".."2000" in it. But the content is just displayed as 2000 lines of divs. I tried setting parent div max-height, but it seems to have no effect on the number of items rendered (still all of them are rendered). Documentation is very sparse.

```
<div style="max-height:100px">
  <Virtualize Items="myData">
    <div>@context</div>
  </Virtualize>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting style overflow: auto;

```
<div style="max-height:100px; overflow: auto;">
    <Virtualize Items="myData">
          <div>@context</div>
    </Virtualize>
</div>
```